# How I get views class name? Like ('.view-id-someview')?

Tags: php, css, drupal-7

I'm trying to get views class name

```
$views_page = views_get_page_view();
if (isset($views_page)) {
   print $views_page->name;
}
```

But above code does not work.

how I get views class name like `'.view-id-someview'`?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which hook you put your code in.

Here are 2 options:

This would go in your theme's template.php file

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_views_view(&$variables) {
    $variables['classes'][] = 'new-class';
}
```

Or another option... this would go in a custom module.

```
function my_module_views_pre_render(&$view) {
    $view->display_handler->set_option('css_class', 'yourclass');
}
```

Comment: thank for reply.I don' want to write new class for view.but I need exists class of views.